# What settings do I need on the glare node to replicate the look of EEVEE's bloom in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, glare

I have a scene that I designed in EEVEE, which looks amazing with Bloom activated, but would look even better with Global Illumination and better reflections. The problem is that using Cycles with the Glare node gives me a different glow than using EEVEE with bloom on. Any idea on what settings to tweak, or what other node I should be using ? I'm using Blender 4.0.1 btw.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your project, but I usually use the Fog Glow setting of the Glare node.